# Unetbootin Critical Error

Tags: unetbootin

I installed Unetbootin through Linux terminal but I faced these errors. please help if you know how to fix these errors.

here's a screenshot of my terminal:

```
root@root:/home# sudo unetbootin
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x147
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a0000f
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x147
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a0001d
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a0001e
X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
  Major opcode: 54 (X_FreePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a0001e
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 2 (X_ShmDetach)
  Resource id:  0x3a0001d
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
```

Comment: Please help us help you by answering the following questions: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Are you running Xorg or Wayland for the desktop? Which version of Unetbootin did you install? From where and how did you install it?

Comment: 1- Ubuntu 18.04
2- No
3- Binaries: 64-bit
4- https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: Are you running Xorg or Wayland for the desktop?
I meant No I don't run Xorg or Wayland for the desktop

Comment: Even when I launch the Unetbootin a blank Pop-up window just appear that's it

Comment: You could try another tool to create an Ubuntu live drive. If it is enough with a live-only drive, you can use a cloning tool, for example Ubuntu's own Startup Disk Creator. If you want a persistent live drive, you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: If you have a graphical desktop (not only a text screen), I think you have either of them. If you have not actively selected Wayland, I think you have Xorg in Ubuntu 18.04.2. - I have not downloaded the binary files, but installed via the Ubuntu PPA with the three command lines shown above the buttons for the binaries. I tested today and it works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. There are details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unetbootin works in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, when installed like this:

- Check that you have the repository Universe

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  ```
- Install the Unetbootin PPA according to the link https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install unetbootin
  ```
- Start Unetbootin with the command suggested, when you try without `sudo`

  ```
  sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/bin/unetbootin
  ```
- After these steps Unetbootin works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (with Xorg), but it is slow, so don't give up even if it seems to get stuck.